# Is Java evaluation order guaranteed in this case of method call and arguments passed in

Tags: java, runtime, compiler-optimization, execution, operator-precedence

I did some reading up on JLS [15.7.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.4) and [15.12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2), but it doesn't guarantee that there won't be any **compiler/runtime optimization** that would *change* the order in which method arguments are evaluated.

*Assume the following code:*

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  MyObject obj = new MyObject();
  methodRelyingOnEvalOrder(obj, obj.myMethod());
}

public static Object methodRelyingOnEvalOrder(MyObject obj, Object input) {
  if (obj.myBoolean())
    return null;
  else
    return input;
}
```

Is it guaranteed that the compiler or runtime **will not** do a false optimization such as the following? This optimization may appear correct, but it is wrong when the order of evaluation matters.

In the case where calling `obj.myMethod` alters the value that will be returned by `obj.myBoolean`, it is crucial that `obj.myMethod` be called first as `methodRelyingOnEvalOrder` requires this alteration to happen first.

```
//*******************************
//Unwanted optimization possible:
//*******************************
public static void main (String[] args) {
  MyObject obj = new MyObject();
  methodRelyingOnEvalOrder(obj);
}

public static Object methodRelyingOnEvalOrder(MyObject obj) {
  if (obj.myBoolean())
    return null;
  else
    return obj.myMethod();
}
//*******************************
```

**If possible,** please show some sources or Java documentation that supports your answer.

**Note:** Please do not ask to rewrite the code. This is a specific case where I am questioning the evaluation order guarantee and the compiler/runtime optimization guarantee. The execution of `obj.myMethod` must happen in the `main` method.

Comment: You can sure the `javac` does almost no optimisations at all, it is all done by the JIT.  While it may re-order or even eliminate the method call, the end behaviour should be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bit of the JLS you referred to (15.7.4) *does* guarantee that:

> Each argument expression appears to be fully evaluated before any part of any argument expression to its right.

and also in 15.12.4.2:

> Evaluation then continues, using the argument values, as described below.

The "appears to" part allows for some optimization, but it must not be *visible*. The fact that all the arguments are evaluated *before* "evaluation then continues" shows that the arguments are really fully evaluted before the method executes. (Or at least, that's the visible result.)

So for example, if you had code of:

```
int x = 10;
foo(x + 5, x + 20);
```

it would be *possible* to optimize that to evaluate both `x + 5` and `x + 20` in parallel: there's no way you could detect this occurring.

But in the case you've given, you *would* be able to detect the call to `obj.myMethod` occurring after the call to `obj.myBoolean()`, so that *wouldn't* be a valid optimization at all.

In short: you're fine to assume that everything will execute in the obvious way here.

Comment: Can you further explain what the JLS means by _appears to be_ and why it is not _is_? And what does not being visible mean?

Comment: @ADTC: It means you won't be able to *detect* any optimization here - it's a truly invisible optimization, if any is applied.

Comment: My gut agrees, but what that section actually says (the part you left out) is `If the evaluation of any argument expression completes abruptly, then no part of any argument expression to its right appears to have been evaluated.` It does not, at least from what I see in that section, explicitly specify what the apparent evaluation order should be if none of the evaluations complete abruptly.

Comment: @Jon What kind of invisible optimizations can happen? Can it do the one suggested in my second code block? If yes, in what circumstances? If no, then all is good :)

Comment: @JasonC: I left that out as I didn't feel it was immediately relevant. That part is in a separate paragraph to the bit that I quoted - there's no indication (as far as I can tell) that the apparent evaluation order is predicated on any evaluation completing abruptly.

Comment: @ADTC: No, the one in your second code block wouldn't be invisible, would it? You could detect it, so it's not a valid optimization.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's very relevant, I think, because it is quite different from "arguments always appear to be evaluated left to right". It only says that if one of the evaluations throw an exception, then the ones to the right do not appear to be evaluated. It does not say what you claimed it says. This isn't a criticism of you, sorry if it reads that way. It's just not how I'm reading that section.

Comment: @JasonC: No, that's a different paragraph. The bit that I quoted does not depend on the bit you're quoting. Those are two independent guarantees. (Or rather, I'd say that the bit you're quoting just clarifies the bit I'm quoting in the case of an exception. It doesn't in any way say "the previous paragraph doesn't apply if no exceptions are thrown.")

Comment: Oh. It's in 15.7.4, not 15.12.4.2.

Comment: @JasonC: Fixed that, thanks. I had both bits open in different tabs - copied the wrong number :(

Comment: Thanks both. @JasonC he is right, it's a different guarantee. But you are also right that it's relevant. For example if `myMethod` can throw an exception, the order in which it is executed relative to `myBoolean` (which may also throw an exception) determines which exception _is_ thrown when either could be thrown. But as Jon has pointed out, it is guaranteed that the order as I wrote in code is guaranteed (no _visible_ optimization) during runtime, so all is good.

Comment: @ADTC: As user2758929 pointed out in his answer, the "unwanted optimization" you proposed is not possible. If `myMethod` throws in your first example, `myBoolean` will never even be executed, as the argument evaluation *must* appear to happen first.

Comment: @JasonC yes, I agree. I'm just pointing out how your comment could be relevant to the question since throwing an exception is one form of _"completes abruptly"_.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the argument evaluation order, the overview of the steps preformed when invoking a method, *and their order*, explained in section [15.12.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4), makes it clear that all argument evaluations are performed before executing the method's code. Quote:

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target
>   reference may be computed. **Second, the argument expressions are
>   evaluated**. Third, the accessibility of the method to be invoked is
>   checked. Fourth, the actual code for the method to be executed is
>   located. **Fifth, a new activation frame is created, synchronization is
>   performed if necessary, and control is transferred to the method code**.

The case you presented where an argument is only evaluated *after* control has been transferred to the method code is out of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I can only accept one answer, but I have upvoted you :)