# Will a ConcurrentHashMap ever expose a partially constructed object via get()?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

The [JavaDoc for `ConcurrentHashMap` states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)

Since "an update operation for a given key... happens-before... any (non-null) retrieval for that key" and a partially constructed object is considered non-null,* would the following code potentially allow `Thread2` to access partially constructed objects?

**`Thread1`:**

```
// Immutable Object (all fields final)
concurrentHashMap.put("immutableObject", new ImmutableObject());

// Volatile Object (all fields volatile)
concurrentHashMap.put("volatileObject", new VolatileObject());

// Thread-safe Mutable Object
concurrentHashMap.put("mutableObject", new MutableObject());
```

**`Thread2`:**

```
concurrentHashMap.get("immutableObject");
concurrentHashMap.get("volatileObject");
concurrentHashMap.get("mutableObject");
```

Is there any need to perform some kind of synchronization in the constructors of these objects to ensure that no thread accesses them before they are fully initialized?

* I'm not 100% sure that partially constructed object is considered non-null, but I haven't seen any evidence to the contrary. It seems like since threads can access partially initialized objects, partially initialized objects must not be null since some of the internal data (whatever is initialized) is accessible.

Comment: No. put won't proceed until the objects are fully constructed.

Comment: @AlexSalauyou not sure how to answer "how", but it is possible. For example https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, you will never have partially constructed objects added to the map.
Arguments are evaluated before being passed to a method.

The [15.12.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4) states indeed that the argument expressions (second step) are evaluated **before** the method execution (last step) :

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target
>   reference may be computed. **Second, the argument expressions are
>   evaluated**. Third, the accessibility of the method to be invoked is
>   checked. Fourth, the actual code for the method to be executed is
>   located. **Fifth, a new activation frame is created, synchronization is
>   performed if necessary, and control is transferred to the method code**.

So here :

```
concurrentHashMap.put("immutableObject", new ImmutableObject());
```

`new ImmutableObject()` is evaluated and the `ImmutableObject` object is fully build before that it is passed to the `concurrentHashMap.put(..)` method.

Comment: Wow, that's obvious! I don't know why I didn't realize that. Here's some references to the Java SE spec which state that arguments are evaluated before being passed to the method: [15.12.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4) and [15.12.4.2. Evaluate Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2)

Comment: (or at least [arguments *appear* to be evaluated before being passed to the method which is good enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181170/is-java-evaluation-order-guaranteed-in-this-case-of-method-call-and-arguments-pa#18181292))

Comment: As I read your question, it was exactly what I though :-) Thank your for the JLS ref, I updated my answer with the part that refers to.

Answer (score 1):

The invocations of `put` will each block until each constructor is finished, thus making the `put` operation atomic.

Therefore, if the `get` invocations are not sequential to the `put` invocations, they may either query the map while the key value pair is already in there, or not and yield `null`.

Here's a minimal example that will run forever, to illustrate:

```
Map<String, Foo> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.put("", new Foo());

class Foo {
    Foo() {
        while (true) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This example was helpful to me, I created a thread that puts `Foo` in the map and another thread that tries to obtain it over and over. The second thread will never retrieve a partially constructed object. Instead it will always get `null`.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 precisely. As the constructor never finishes doing its job, the `put` operation never succeeds and any `get` invocation will return `null` for that key (assuming the key is not already present, that is).

Answer (score 0):

```
concurrentHashMap.put("immutableObject", new ImmutableObject());
```

This line does 2 things in the following order:

1. create a new ImmutableObject
2. add the created object to the hashmap

So the answer is no, the hashmap cannot return partially constructed objects as the objects are constructed completely before tehy are even added to the hashmap.